# Get html element rendered height with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

A really simple question.

For example, I have a class like this:

```
.someclass {
  font-size: 1.2em /* let's say that 1em is set to 10px in this example */
  padding: 1em 0 2em 0;
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
}
```

And some simple html to use it:

```
<div class="someclass">Test</div>
```

I would like to get the generated height of this element - computed height with border and padding. Using jQuery `.height()` method in this example gives the current value of `line-height` property - as expected, because the text in the div has only one line.

I know I could do the calculations myself as they are relatively simple but I'd like to ask - is there a built-in solution for that in jQuery?

Comment: I accepted yours because of the overall value ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has several methods to do just this.  See http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/

In this case, it sounds like you want `outerHeight()`.  http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

Answer (score 1):

go for [`innerHeight`](http://api.jquery.com/innerHeight/)

This method returns the height of the element, including top and bottom padding, in pixels.

Comment: add (borderwidth*2) in width and height manually ( if it is in px then)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.outerHeight()`.

http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/

> Get the current computed height for the first element in the set of
>   matched elements, **including padding, border**, and optionally margin.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [.outerHeight() - jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)