# How to find the rendered height of a DIV with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, haml

I am attempting to find the rendered height of two div. They have the same class (.defense) but are within separate containers (side-1 and side-2). I need to use these heights, as the height is set to auto in the CSS, to use in my jQuery to decide which should the be the height of both divs when loaded.

Here is my jQuery code:
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).load(function() {

```
      var sideOneDefense = $('.side-1 .defense').height();
      var sideTwoDefense = $('.side-2 .defense').height();

      if (sideOneDefense >= sideTwoDefense) {
        $('.defense').css("height",sideOneDefense)
      }
      else {
        $('.defense').css("height",sideTwoDefense)
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post any relevant CSS for these classes?

Comment: That should work perfectly. What is your problem?

Comment: This returns a height: 0px;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711822/get-html-element-rendered-height-with-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You are using the code on load by the way after dom is ready the value is not what you expect. Use the code inside ready handler instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sideOneDefense = $('.side-1 .defense').height();
  var sideTwoDefense = $('.side-2 .defense').height();

  if (sideOneDefense >= sideTwoDefense) {
    $('.defense').css("height",sideOneDefense)
  }
  else {
    $('.defense').css("height",sideTwoDefense)
  }
});
```

Comment: Whether I use ready handler or load handler I am getting a height of 0px. But this is not correct as both elements have a height that is greater than 0px.